# Tracking event start time on server

Tags: php, websocket, cron

I'm currently working on a project where we have an event-management system,

I'd like to send customers a notification when the event they're attending starts and after it's finished.

I tried to search the internet if there is a better solution than running a cronjob every 5 minutes (which is still inaccurate),

What I exactly want to do is, if an event starts by 9:00 PM, I need to tell the server to execute some task if it's 9:00 PM. If another one starts by 4:00 AM, execute a task on 4:00 AM.

I've read about websockets but I don't know if it's applicable here,
And I'd be very thankful if you shared some thoughts with me.

Comment: how are conjobs " inaccurate" ?

Comment: You could take a look at reactphp. http://reactphp.org it is an astnc php socket server framework (sort of) which could be used for this project. They've got some great examples te get you started. Also enough tutorials online

Comment: @nogad If an event in the database starts at 4:00 PM and the last run of the cron job was on 3:59 then the next run will be on 4:04 which is 4 minutes late hence "inaccurate"

Comment: @BertBijn That's awesome, thanks a lot

Comment: so run a cronjob every minute

Comment: @nogad still overlapping might occur if the last run is not finished yet. besides this will affect the performance badly as the CPU usage will be very high